# Мета-тег og:description кривой

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

```
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Q&amp;A for программистов" />
```

С локализацией косяк. Если отправлять ссылку через какой-нибудь телеграм, выглядит нелепо :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для тех, кто в танке (как автор этого дополнения): "Q&A for" не переведено.

Comment: Спасибо за напоминание! Добавил приоритет этой задаче.

Comment: Хм, какой интересный баг. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Непереводимая надпись "Q&A for" не только здесь встречается, странно, что вы её раньше не видели.

Comment: @Discord конечно видел, просто не понял, что речь об этом. ) думал, что-то не так с тегами на странице.

Comment: Только что заметил то же самое, хотел зарепортить, а оно уже год висит, оказывается. Хорошая работа, админы ;)